# Java : getParameter

Tags: java

```
lStrABC     = UTIL_COMMON.fnGetValue(req.getParameter("ABC"));
```

hi, please help to define the above code? the "ABC" is wat? variables? come from the  ma?

thanks

Comment: the code snippet you posted has too little information to infer what ABC is other than it is a string. 

I would guess, req has some parameters and one of them is named ABC.

Comment: Nice example of obfuscated code ;)

Comment: What is "ma"? ----------

Comment: There really should be some sort of switch on javac to warn about daft naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the snippet i assume its in a Java Servlet.

If so, "ABC" is the name of a form field on the submitted form, with the getParameter method retrieving the value of the form field.

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/128.html

Answer (score 0):

"ABC" is just a string, a string literal to be precise.

In this case I assume it's the name of some parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The Object referenced by `req` provides access to a parameter store. Parameters are key/value pairs in your case. To get a parameter, you need a key, and the String literal `"ABC"` is one of those keys.

If you want to know, why it's `"ABC"` in this case, than you have to look in the underlying parameter store itself (flat file, database) or analyse the code and find the code point, where this key/value pair is actually stored.